# How to Handle DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00', '24:20') Like scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

There is a column in my Table. In which we are storing string value in format `'HH:MM'`.During fetching records with this table every things works ok with

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00', ColumnName)
```

Problem is when we have Value greater than `23:59`.
Its showing error like

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can anybody suggest me the right approach for achieving this scenario.

Comment: The right approach is to use appropriate datatypes.

Comment: Actually we have to save value greater then '23:59' so that we have taken the datatype as Varchar.

Comment: Something like `'24:20'` isn't convertible to `TIME` or `DateTIME` directly. your best bet might be to split it using `:` and then multiply hours by 60 and add minutes

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a data type that represents a time span (it only has a type that represents a time of day). As such, the most natural way to represent this data is probably as an `int` number of minutes (if you need minutes granularity). Leave converting that into a `hh:mm` *string* (or converting *from* such strings) as a UI concern, and nowhere near the DB.

Comment: What does '24:20' actually represent?  It's not a valid time of day.

Comment: Basically in this column we are storing Custom value for Time so that we have taken it as varchar . As for our scenario our technician can do work for Multiple days . So that we are storing his Actual Hrs in it may be greater then 23:59.

Comment: @ughai your suggestion for splitting on behalf of ':' looks ok to me. Will it decrease my performance as  we have to retrieve lots of records . and Can you please provide the sample code snipped for this.

Comment: yes it will. if you had defined hours and minutes separately or even a single int column as minutes, it would have been faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like your saving the length of a time period. Try storing it in minutes. My query can handle numbers of different lengths since it's based on the colon.

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (ColumnName VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES  ('100:00'),
        ('24:20');

SELECT  ColumnName,
        (hr * 60) + minut AS time_period_in_minutes
FROM @yourTable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(ColumnName,0,CHARINDEX(':',ColumnName)) AS INT),
                    CAST(SUBSTRING(ColumnName,CHARINDEX(':',ColumnName) + 1,LEN(ColumnName)) AS INT)) CA(hr,minut)
```

Results:

```
ColumnName time_period_in_minutes
---------- ----------------------
100:00     6000
24:20      1460
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are storing the value as something other than a time, why not just store the number of minutes and convert to whatever format you want on output?

Otherwise, I would suggest that you simply convert the value to minutes:

```
select (cast(left(ColumnName, 2) as int) * 60 +
        cast(right(ColumnName, 2) as int)
       ) as Minutes
```

If you are not using date/time values, there is no requirement for using the functions *specifically* designed for them.

EDIT:

To handle hours longer than 99, use `charindex()`:

```
select (cast(left(ColumnName, charindex(':', ColumnName) - 1) as int) * 60 +
        cast(right(ColumnName, 2) as int)
       ) as Minutes
```

Comment: It is being failed in case when we have '100:00' like value.

Comment: @AshishBisht . . . See the edit.  It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

```
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00', case when ISDATE(ColumnName)=0 then '00:00' else ColumnName end )
```